# Can not add activeClassName or activeStyle to my react Navlinks React Router DOM

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have e category navlinks comes from backend api. When I want to add Navlink activeClassname or activeStyle. For example when I tried to add `activeStyle={{color: "red" }}` all my links turn to red How can I fix this problem ?

```js
 const  categoryList = this.state.categories.map((category) => (
       <li className="navlist-item" key={category.id}  onClick={() => this.closeAll()}>
             <NavLink activeStyle={{color: "red" }} to={"/product-list?categories="+category.id}>{category.name}</NavLink>
       </li> 
  ));
```

Comment: I have tried to add 'exact' to navlinks but it did not help